# How to running Shell scrpit with parameter in progress-4gl

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm having trouble running a shell script command in progress-4gl.

I have an A.xml file and the shell script moveXml.sh is used to FTP move the A.xml file from a Linux server to a window server.

my shell script needs 1 (one) parameter = </filename ex: A.xml> to work.

Below is my syntax to run moveXml.sh in progress-4gl.

OS-COMMAND COLD VALUE ("moveXml.sh").

But I can't pass the parameters.

How to pass parameters to moveXml.sh.
please help me.

Comment: What is the purpose of ``COLD`` ? As written, ``os-command`` will try to execute COLD passing 'moveXml.sh' as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using [`os-command`](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920676570.html) you can use value, you pass the entire command line:

```
os-command value( 'moveXml.sh A.xml' ).
```